# Windows Mobile Device Center stops working after "not supported bluetooth function" driver is installed

Tags: sdk, windows-mobile, driver

I run the drvupdate-64 installer which runs until it closes and I get a notification in the tray icon that '"not supported bluetooth function"' was successfully installed as a driver.

I found that a bit weird and after that NOTHING happens with the installer, it just dissapers and doesn't come back.

In task manager I can see it running as 'driver_setup.exe' with the description 'windows mobile device center setup' but that's it, nothing else seems to be happening.

Any ideas what's going wrong and how I can fix this? I need it to get the windows mobile sdk to install.

Comment: What is **drvupdate-64 installer**? Could you update the question with information on this product? Also, what device are you installing this on? What version of Windows Mobile is it running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to navigate to the install directory of WMDC Driver Update and find the installer to continue the process, the installer was bugging out on me and not proceeding to the next step for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when installing on Dell laptops models 7480, 7280. I had tried updating removing device drivers as per [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-mobile-device-center-installation-issue/97ae5162-72a4-4467-9e5d-e1c7ce2d0afa?auth=1) with no success.

Having come across the above I did continue the installer process as per tweetypi comment but still had issues. I was able to install and get this working as per following steps:

After running the WMDC installer I could see that in task manager the install process "driver_setup.exe" was still running.

As per tweetypi answers I then navigated to the install directory for WMDC Driver Update to find the installer and continue the process:
C:\Windows\WindowsMobile

I opened each Drivers folder (Bluetooth, RNDIS, Serial) in turn and run the “wmupdate” installer.

Windows Mobile Device Centre was then listed on my programs list but would not launch.

I then opened Device Manager from Control Panel. Changed view to show hidden devices. This revealed 'Bluetooth Virtual Devices' > 'Not Supported Bluetooth function'.

I then uninstalled this driver and checked delete the driver software for this device

After this, I ended the “driver_setup.exe” process within task manager. Then run the “driver_setup.exe” install file once more. The install process was then able to complete and the Windows Mobile Device Centre was now launching.

The device I needed to connect was for USB, I'm not sure about functionality for Bluetooth after removing the virtual device.